# dcm4chee dcm4jboss ejb build fail build.xml

Tags: dcm4che

*I build Ant file build.xml but it fail and appear error:*

```
{BUILD FAILED

Projects\source\dcm4jboss-all\dcm4jboss-ejb\build.xml:145: taskdef A class needed by class xdoclet.modules.ejb.EjbDocletTask cannot be found: xjavadoc/ant/XJavadocTask.


File build.properties: 
#javac options
javac.debug=on
javac.deprecation=off
javac.optimize=on
javac.source=1.5
javac.target=1.5

#Override with your dcm4che-1.4.x dist location
dcm4che14.home= D:\Works\Projects\source\dcm4che14

#Override with your XDoclet dist location
xdoclet.home= D:/Works/Projects/Pacs/Buildpath/xdoclet1.2.3

#Override with your Cactus dist location
cactus.home=D:/Works/Projects/Pacs/Buildpath/cactus-1.8.1-bin

#Override with your JBoss dist location
jboss.home= D:/Works/Projects/Pacs/Buildpath/jboss-4.2.3.GA

}
```

Question:

1. what happend?
2. how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try some way below:

1. Try to edit PATH for JAVA_HOME to jdk6
2. Add Xdoclet library to your project/lib
3. Try a clean build
4. Redownload source from dcm4che and copy xdoclet,... to {user.home}, do not change build.xml

Hope this help